# Java Regex Missing a Match

Tags: java

I'm trying to return a string of regular expression matches. Specifically, trying to return all vowels (aeiou) found in a string. The following code returns the 2 oo's but not the e. 
Expecting: eoo
Getting: oo

Why is it not finding and appending the e to the StringBuilder object? Thank you.

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inp = "Hello World!";
    System.out.println(vowelOnly(inp));
  }

  public static String vowelOnly(String input) {
    Pattern vowelPattern = Pattern.compile("[aeiou]+");
    Matcher vowelMatcher = vowelPattern.matcher(input);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int i = 0;
    if (vowelMatcher.find()) {
      while (vowelMatcher.find( )) {
        sb.append(vowelMatcher.group());
        i++;
      } 
      return sb.toString();
    } else {
      return "No matches";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you are not considering the result of first `find`, the one in `if (vowelMatcher.find())` - remove that `if` and, if you really need the `"No matches"` return, test `sb` after the loop (I would prefer returning just the empty string, since that is what the method found [message, if needed, created by caller])

Comment: If this is for a university project, returning "No matches" is acceptable. For almost every other context, it is better to return either an empty `String`, an `Optional<String>`, or throw an exception, but in this case, using an `Optional` or throwing an exception is probably overkill.

Comment: you can also just add `sb.append(...group())` just after that `if`, but code repetition isn't that good

Answer (score 4):

When you call `vowelMatcher.find()` inside your `if` condition, you tell the matcher to find the first string matching the specified pattern. In this case, it is "e". When you call it again in your `while` condition, the matcher finds the next match, in this case it is "o".

From there, it loops through the rest of the `String`. If you gave it the input "Hello World eeee", it would return "ooeeee", since you always discard the first match by calling `.find()` without calling `.group()` immediately after.

Change your loop to be like this, and it should work:

```
int i = 0;
while (vowelMatcher.find()) {
    sb.append(vowelMatcher.group());
    i++;
}

return i == 0 ? "No matches" : sb.toString();  // return "no matches" if i is 0, otherwise, string
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first call to `vowelMatcher.find()` in the if statement finds the "e" and the subsequent calls to `vowelMatcher.find()` in the while loop find all subsequent vowels.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what you need:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inp = "Hello World!";
    System.out.println(vowelOnly(inp));
  }

  public static String vowelOnly(String input) {
    Pattern vowelPattern = Pattern.compile("[aeiou]+");
    Matcher vowelMatcher = vowelPattern.matcher(input);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int i = 0;

    while (vowelMatcher.find()) {
      sb.append(vowelMatcher.group());
      i++;
    }
    return i == 0 ? "No matches" : sb.toString();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That would probably be the solution you're looking for:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inp = "Hello World!";
    System.out.println(vowelOnly(inp));
  }

  public static String vowelOnly(String input) {
    Pattern vowelPattern = Pattern.compile("[aeiou]+");
    Matcher vowelMatcher = vowelPattern.matcher(input);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (vowelMatcher.find()) {
      sb.append(vowelMatcher.group());
    }

    if (sb.length() == 0) {
      return "No matches";
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Couple of notes:

- You don't need to import `java.lang.*` classes.
- With the matcher, whatever you `find`, you should `group` it immediately to collect.
- You don't need the iteration variable. `StringBuilder.length()` would simply reveal if it's empty.